# How do I get info from an embed?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I've been making a suggestion command and I want it so that I can use a `-approve <The message id>` to edit the message. The problem is when I try to fetch info from it using

```
const Suggestionchannel = client.channels.cache.get("833796404383973442");
const messages = Suggestionchannel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 })
```

it only fetches all the messages and not the embeds. I want it to fetch the embeds so I can get the data and edit the message by its id. With the data, I could display who made the suggestion and what the suggestion was while at the same time showing that it was approved. How would I get the info from an embed using a message id?

On a side note: I know I could use async and await to easily edit it while on the same code but I want it so that it's accessible. If I do that and restart the bot, I won't be able to approve the previous suggestions, only the new ones after I restart the bot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to either await fetching the messages from the suggestion channel, or put it into a `.then` to not have `messages` be a Promise. Awaiting it wouldn't change anything in your ability to edit the message, you just have to make sure your message cache has the actual message in it.

Fetching the messages from a channel would return a `Promise<Collection<Snowflake, Message>>`. Once you resolve the message, you get a collection containing messages. On the Message class, there is a array called `embeds`. It contains all of the embeds part of the message, normally, if sent by a bot, only contains one `MessageEmbed`.

Another thing is, to make it easier for you, the fetch message also takes in a message ID, and if it's provided, it would fetch the message with that ID from the channel. Doing this would change what it returns to `Promise<Message>`

Implementing all of these changes in your code would look something like;

```js
const Suggestionchannel = client.channels.cache.get("833796404383973442");
// make sure that your outer scope is asynchronous
const message = await Suggestionchannel.messages.fetch('INSERT MESSAGE ID OR VARIABLE HERE')
const embed = message.embeds[0]
//would be undefined if there is no embed
//would be a MessageEmbed if there is an embed
```